# Angular ng-repeat and dynamic properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a php object that I pass to ng through a function. This object has several properties such as : paragraphe1, paragraphe2, paragraphe3 up to 8.

I try to display it with a ng-repeat loop like :

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
Paragraphe {{i}} >> {{paragraphe+i}}
</div>
```

It shows :

- Paragraphe 1 >> 1
- Paragraphe 2 >> 2
- ...
- Paragraphe 8 >> 8

instead of the content of paragraphe1, ....8

Thanks for your help.
FX

Comment: "This object has several properties ...": Is it exposed in the scope? What's the name of the object?

Comment: show us the defenition of "paragraphe". it should be defined in the relvant scope.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your paragraph definition is:

```
$scope.paragraph = {
    paragraph1: 'lorem ipsum 1',
    paragraph2: 'lorem ipsum 2',
    paragraph3: 'lorem ipsum 3',
    // ...
}
```

The template should look like:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
    Paragraphe {{i}} >> {{paragraph['paragraph' + i]}}
</div>
```

See **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4an3fwqm/)**

Comment: While this is possible, I would still strongly recommend to pass the `paragrapheX`-properties as an array instead of generated-name-properties

Comment: Thank you ! That's what I was looking for ! Sorry for incomplete explanation / definition... you assumed right

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the values hard coded you can make use of key, value pairs in the ng-repeat

**view:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in paragraph">
    {{key}} >> {{value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
// module
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// filter
app.filter('dayFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var filterFunction = function (item) {
        return item.days >= 1 && item.days <= 7;
    };
    return input.filter(filterFunction);
  };
});

//controller
app.controller('demoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.paragraph = {
    paragraph1: 'lorem ipsum 1',
    paragraph2: 'lorem ipsum 2',
    paragraph3: 'lorem ipsum 3'
  }
});
```